# Getting rid of parentheses after dictionary intersection

Tags: python, dictionary, intersection

There is one question I am working on and got a very close answer... basically, the question is that you get two dictionaries and you have to find elements that intersect from both dictionaries and then create those elements (one same key from both dicts and two values from both dics) in a new dictionary.

```
a = {'A':17,'B':31,'C':42,'D':7,'E':46,'F':39,'G':9}
b = {'D':8,'E':3,'F':2,'g':5}

def intersect(a,b):
    c = set(a).intersection(set(b))
    d = {}
    for i in c:
        if i in a:
            d[i] = int(a[i]),int(b[i])
    return d

OUTPUT: {'E': (46, 3), 'D': (7, 8), 'F': (39, 2)}
```

I want to get the output like {'E': 46, 3, 'D': 7, 8, 'F': 39, 2}

How do I get rid of the parentheses around the values?

Comment: The output that you want is a `string` or a `dict`? Because you can't get a dictionary like that (but you could change its representation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code as you have written won't output anything at all. However, if you want to remove parentheses, then you can use this.

```
str(intersect(a, b)).replace('(', '').replace(')', '')
```

or equivalently this, which is a bit more concise and efficient

```
str(intersect(a, b)).translate(None, '()')
```

Answer (score 0):

The output you are seeing is the python representation of your dictionary. What you have built (and, as far as I can tell, you have built it correctly -- it's what you want) is a dictionary mapping keys to pairs of items. The pairs are tuples, and those get printed with parentheses around them.

It sounds like what you want is an method which takes your dictionary and prints it, formatted in a specific way.

Something like this would print the dictionary the way you want it to:

```
def dictionary_printer(d):
    print "{%s}" % ', '.join(
        [("'%s': %s" % (key, ', '.join(map(str,value))))
        for key, value in d.items()]
    )
```